# Rust — why is there a warning "value captured by `online` is never read" here?

Tags: rust, warnings, spawn

Why does the Rust compiler issue this warning?

> value captured by `online` is never read

```rust
use std::{thread, time::Duration};
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut online = false;

    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            if let Some(_) = get_rand_option() {
                online = true;    // why is there a warning here?
            } else {
                online = false;
            }

            if online {           // is the value not being read here?
                println!("Yee");
            } else {
                println!("...");
            }
        }
    });

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100000));
}

fn get_rand_option() -> Option<i32> {
    rand::thread_rng().gen::<Option<i32>>()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust is smart enough to know that you will initialize that variable before using it, so it tells you that giving it a value before that is superfluous. I also moved the variable declaration inside the closure, since it is permanently moved inside it anyway otherwise.

Note that for this minimal example, you might as well just declare `online` inside the loop, since you never break out of it or use the value from a previous iteration: `let online = if let …`

```
use std::{thread, time::Duration};
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {

    thread::spawn(|| {
        let mut online: bool;
        loop {
            // using the fact that ‘if let’ is an expression
            online = if let Some(_) = get_rand_option() {
                true
            } else {
                false
            };

            if online {         
                println!("Yee");
            } else {
                println!("...");
            }
        }
    });

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100000));
}

fn get_rand_option() -> Option<i32> {
    rand::thread_rng().gen::<Option<i32>>()
}
```

Comment: Eactly, I didn’t think to move the variable declaration.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how much the example was an oversimplification of the problem but the `online = if let Some(_) = get_rand_option() {` construct in this case would be much better written as `online = get_rand_option().is_some()`

Answer (score 1):

This is because the initial value `false` (by line 4 `let mut online = false;`) is never used after being captured by the closure.

If you use `online` once in the closure before re-assignment, I guess the warning would disappear. e.g.

```
use rand::Rng;
use std::{thread, time::Duration};

fn main() {
    let mut online = false;

    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            if online {
                println!("Yee");
            } else {
                println!("...");
            }

            if let Some(_) = get_rand_option() {
                online = true; 
            } else {
                online = false;
            }
        }
    });

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100000));
}

fn get_rand_option() -> Option<i32> {
    rand::thread_rng().gen::<Option<i32>>()
}
```

Basicly, the compiler is not aware of your logic and purpose, so it will remind you of that meaningless assignment. If you just want to keep the logic unchanged, then you could add `#[allow(unused_assignments)]` above the declaration of `online`

```
#[allow(unused_assignments)]
let mut online = false;
```

or just change the variable name to `_online`

```
let mut _online = false;
```

to let compiler ignore this warning.

Comment: But the logic is changing. It is not known what the value of "online" will be, before printing, you must first call "get_rand_option". The original assignment "online" is made meaningless to prevent the compiler from throwing another error.

Comment: Yeah, the compiler is not aware of your logic and purpose, so it will remind you of that meaningless assignment. If you just want to keep the logic unchanged, then you add `#[allow(unused_assignments)]` above the declaration of `online`, or just add `_` prefix to `online` (i.e. `_online`) to let compiler ignore the unread.